# R count of instances where i and j are equal

Tags: r, count, multiple-columns

I am trying to get a count of instances where values in two columns are equal.  However, my equation is not working.

Can someone point out where this is wrong??

```
count<-0 
for (i in 1:length(v1)){
  for (j in 1:length(v2)){
    if (i == j){
      count <- count+ 1 }
  }
}
```

Comment: As it stands, this is far too broad.  What is `v1`?  What is `v2`?  What is the desired result? Please add these to your post.

Comment: Why wouldn't a simpler approach just be: `min( length(v1), length(v2) )`. Furthermore, the code works for two vectors of unequal length.

Comment: `sum(i==j)` or `cumsum(i==j)` would be my guess actually.

Comment: I'll take `sum(v1 %in% v2)` for 200, Alex.

Comment: it's irrelevant what the columns are.  the point is I want to sum the instances where they are equivalent.

sum.me<- A==B
sum(sum.me)

answers it...though there are other ways, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are comparing indices (i==j) instead of contents of each cell (v1[i] and v2[j]). You should write it in this way:

```
    count<-0 
for (i in 1:length(v1))
{
    for (j in 1:length(v2))
    {
        if (v1[i] == v2[j])
        {
            count <- count+ 1 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some example data:

```
set.seed(42)
v1 <- sample(0:1, 3, TRUE)
#[1] 1 1 0
v2 <- sample(0:1, 3, TRUE)
#[1] 1 1 1
```

Judging from the accepted answer, you want this:

```
sum(outer(v1, v2, "=="))
#[1] 6
```

Note that this solution will be much faster than the double `for` loop. However, it needs more memory, which could become a problem for huge vectors (because it calculates a matrix that grows quadratic with vector length).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.   If you have two columns in a dataframe and you want to know how many times that the values are the same, then this works...

```
a<-1:10
b<-c(2,2,4,2,5,6,1,2,9,10)
df<-data.frame(a,b)

sum(df$a == df$b)   #[1] 5
```

I answer with the caveat that I may be completely missing the point of your question ...

I guess looking at the comments above, your question is more about knowing how many times values of one column/variable appear in that of another - lots of solutions are already posted above

Comment: There is no need to create a dataframe. sum(a==b) would suffice.